# ASP.NET MVC question

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want the following structure in my ASP.NET MVC solution;

Controllers/HomeController.cs
Controllers/Administration/AdministrationController.cs
Controllers/Administration/UsersController.cs

Views/Home/Index.aspx
Views/Administration/Index.aspx
Views/Administration/Users/Index.aspx
Views/Administration/Users/AddUser.aspx
etc.

How can I make it work so I get http://localhost/Administration/Users ? Do I need a route for this, or create a new Administration area?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd love to know an answer to this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an "Administration" area:

http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/what-is-new-in-aspnet-mvc#_TOC3_2